# C++ terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc, protobuf-c

Recently I have started working on Grpc.
On Grpc C++ compilation I get below error, not sure what is caused the issue.

I am not from C++ background, any help will be much useful for me.

[HOSTLD]  Linking /home/test/grpc/bins/opt/grpc_ruby_plugin
[PROTOC]  Generating protobuf CC file from src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.proto
[GRPC]    Generating gRPC's protobuf service CC file from 
src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.proto

***terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'***

what():  Unknown error -1

***--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin killed by signal 6.***

make: *** [/home/test/grpc/gens/src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.grpc.pb.cc] Error 1

Before the I was trying cross compilation and that was resulted in "grpc segmentation fault" on helloworld communication. To clear that I have followed below step.

**I nuked my /usr/local/lib/ and cleared out all proto and grpc libs**

**rm -f /usr/local/lib/libproto* /usr/local/lib/libgrpc***

**Cleaned everything**

**git submodule foreach git clean -xfd**

**git clean -xfd**

Then re-installed everything but still, I get the above error. Can someone please help me on this issue?

**Note:** I removed the complete grpc folder, recloned it. Installed protobuf and the protobuf installation is successful but when I give "make" command in gRPC I get above error.

When I googled it, this looks to be some generic error from c++ side.

Below are steps which I have followed.:

•   git clone -b $(curl -L http://grpc.io/release) https://github.com/grpc/grpc

•    cd grpc

•   git submodule update --init

•   cd third_party/protobuf

•   ./Autogen.sh

•   ./configure

•   make && make install (Protobuf installation is successful)

•   go to grpc folder and give make.

This is not successful, throws terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'

Comment: Use a debugger to find the point where the exception is thrown (this means that there is error checking code in the program which intentionally throws when an OS call returns a failure code)

Comment: It comes from libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc:785] CHECK failed: I am sure that all was working properly, to avoid some issue I have removed "rm -f /usr/local/lib/libproto* /usr/local/lib/libgrpc*" after this only, I am facing all these issues.

Comment: Looks like pthread library is missing but not sure how to add it.

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution for this, its due to pthread was not configured properly.

executing below command from protobuf folder solved the issue.

pkg-config --cflags protobuf         # print compiler flags

pkg-config --libs protobuf           # print linker flags

pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf  # print both

./configure CXXFLAGS="$(pkg-config --cflags protobuf)" LIBS="$(pkg-config --libs protobuf)"

make

[sudo] make install

go to grpc folder and run make command.

Comment: Great! I encountered the same problem, your solution worked for me. Many thanks!

Comment: There is an open issue on github/googlesamples https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-cpp/pull/54, maybe they need take your answer as their solution. I wonder how did you find this solution.

Comment: In my case what I simply needed to do was adding "-lpthread" to my compilation command